# Parsing from Get-LocalGroupMember to Net User <username> /domain

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse the domain from get-localgroupmember and then query that to **net user username /domain** without having to omit the domain manually. This would be extremely fast if I were using bash, as I imagine I would use a couple of text manipulations here and there. But I'm not that verse with Powershell.

Output 1:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-localgroupmember administrators

```
ObjectClass Name                          PrincipalSource
----------- ----                          ---------------
User        DESKTOP-AMAZING\Administrator Local
User        DESKTOP-AMAZING\hot           Local
User        DESKTOP-AMAZING\cold          MicrosoftAccount
```

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> net user hot /domain | findstr "Last logon" (omitting the domain manually)

```
Last Logon     2/1/2021 00:00:00AM
```

Desired output

```
Name   Last Logon
----   -----------
hot    Last Logon     2/1/2021 00:00:00AM
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use PowerShell commands for getting local user information:

```
Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators |
    Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'User' -and $_.PrincipalSource -eq 'Local'} |
        Foreach-Object {
            Get-LocalUser $_.Sid | Select Name,LastLogon
}
```

---

If you must parse and do it the hard way, here would be one approach:

```
Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators | Where ObjectClass -eq 'User' |% {
    $user = $null
    # Split name at first \ and return characters after the \
    $name = ($_.Name -split '\\',2)[1]
    # Checking for local user
    if ($_.PrincipalSource -eq 'Local') {
        $user = net user $name
    }
    # checking for AD user
    elseif ($_.PrincipalSource -eq 'ActiveDirectory') {
        $user = net user $name /DOMAIN
    }
    # LastLogon only matches line that begins Last Logon
    # Last Logon and proceeding spaces are removed from matched line
    # Index [0] is used because -match returns an array when an array is compared
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $name
        LastLogon = ($user -match '^Last Logon' -replace '^Last Logon\s*')[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's clear that I do not understand this completely yet. As some say, in order to explain something simply -- you must understand it fully. This was the straight up answer! Thank you for your answer on this! Much appreciated

Comment: Can I insert another question on this? It seems the server has no way of install get-localgroupmember (production server) at this moment i can only use net localgroup administrators. Is there a way to expand the properties of net localgroup administrators? Please point me in the right direction